# Is it allowed to use @EnableJpaRepositories and @EnableSolrRepositories in one @Configuration class?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-solr

**Quick answer**: Update Spring Framework to at least 4.0.4

This sounds like a bug in `Spring Data Commons` to me.
Depending on the order of `@EnableSolrRepositories` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` Spring tries to set either `solrOperations` on `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` or
`entityManager` on `SolrRepositoryFactoryBean`.

`EnableSolrRepositories` before `EnableJpaRepositories`

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories("package.a")
@EnableJpaRepositories("package.b")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfig {
    ...
}
```

results in

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'solrOperations' of bean class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]: Bean property 'solrOperations' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 107 more
```

`EnableJpaRepositories` before `EnableSolrRepositories`

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("package.b")
@EnableSolrRepositories("package.a")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfig {
    ...
}
```

results in

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'entityManager' of bean class [org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactoryBean]: Bean property 'entityManager' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 77 more
```

I`m using the latest Spring Data releases

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**As a side note**

This error does not occur in my tests where I´m using the same configuration class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyConfig.class})
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
    ....
}
```

It occurs only during deployment on Tomcat (my version is 7.0.54).
Did someone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer**: Update `Spring Framework` to at least 4.0.4

**Long answer**:
After debugging repository initialization I came to the conclusion that the root cause is a buggy implementation of
`AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils#getMergedAnnotationAttributes` method which is used in `AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource`.

This method receives all annotations set on MyConfig class and should return annotation attributes either of `EnableJpaRepository` or `EnableSolrRepository`.
In this case all attributes of `EnableJpaRepository` were overriden by `EnableSolrRepository` and vice versa.

See [SPR-11649](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11649) for more details. This issue was fixed in version 4.0.4